# How much work with cables question

Tags: calculus

How much work is needed for ten cables that each weigh 0.54 lb/in. lift a 3000 lb television set 500 feet? Cables work together and equally share in the weight of the tv set.

All I got was the weight part which is 500*3000 = 1500000 ft lbs. I'm lost after that..

Answer (score 1):

Work = Force applied $\times$ distance. So thats all . The  force of gravity upon the elevator is its weight $mg$ to counter this the resultant force by the ropes should be equal and opposite to gravitational force. The resultant force of 10 cables will be equal to elevator's weight.
Edit: The question seems tricky. But reading competently "*How much work is needed for ten cables....   ....Cables work together....*" means the cables are applying force to the *TV*, the *TV* has risen through 500 feet. The total length of the cables is not mentioned. All we know is that there is some external agency(cables for the present case) which is able to provide sufficient force(weight mg of *TV*) to rise the *point of application of force*( i.e.*TV*). So we are to find the amount of work done **on the *TV*** by the cables.

Comment: So I don't have to do 10 * 0.54? This part confused me when it said "each weighing".

Comment: @user129674 i edited my answer.

Comment: The answer I got was 4578000. Is that right? I converted the lbs per inch to foot.

Comment: @user129674 There is no reason to find the work done on the cables. We dont know the total length of cables so how would we find the total weight of cables. What they have given is _mass per unit length_. I say i use the cables of length 0.000001 inches and its mass will be $(0.54\times0.000001) \approx 0 lbs$ so there will be approximately $0$ work in rising the cables and the work comes out approx 500*3000. Second you say:"_I converted the lbs per inch to foot_" You will have to convert _lbs per inch_ into _lbs per feet_ not only _feet_.